# Debugging my PERFT coding

Tags: engines, castling, perft

I'm stuck debugging my move generation and do move function. I noticed that the castling as actually the problem in my code, but I think I have implemented everything right. I installed some java chess engine in Github that generates moves, to compare it from mine. I separated the nodes into captures, en passant, castling. Just to be sure that the castling is really the problem, I removed the generation of castle for both of my engine and from the one that I installed. I tested 3 positions and everything was fine.

**This is how I generate my castling moves:**

if (sideToMove can castle king side **and** F1|F8 is empty **and** G1|G8 is empty **and** E1|E8 is not attacked by the enemy **and** F1 is not attacked by the enemy)
**add king castle move()**

if (sideToMove can castle queen side and D1|D8 is empty **and** C1|C8 is empty **and** B1|B8 is empty **and** E1|E8 is not attacked **and** D1 is not attacked)
**add queen castle move()**

**This is how I manage castling moves**:

In my do move function, **if a piece is captured, and It is a ROOK**, then remove the castling right depending on the side of the captured rook, and the castle side of that rook (e.g. H1 captured, then remove **king castling**)

The same for the previous one, but **if a rook move once**, then remove the castling right depending of the rook side (oo | ooo)

**If a king castled, or moved once** then remove both castle.

**This is how I represent Castling Rights:**

0000 -> 0 -> no castle

0001 -> 1 -> white king castle

0010 -> 2 -> white queen castle

0100 -> 4 -> black king castle

1000 -> 8 -> black queen castle

So If I want to remove castling right, let's say starting position, has all castles which is equivalent to **1111**.

```
// remove both castle for white

pos.castle_right &= ~(white king castle | white queen castle)

// remove both castle for black

pos.castle_right &= ~(black king castle | black queen castle)
```

and so on

And also, **at the end of my do move function I do this:**

```
// example side is white

... flip side

// becomes black


// simplify to, if black is attacking white king, undo move, return false

                   (attacking side)        (victim square)
if (isSquareAttacked(sideToMove, kingSquareOf(flipSide)) {

  undoMove

  return false

}

return true
```

Am I doing everything right? If you see anything wrong, please point it out for me.

Edit:

I found the bug, It turns out that my bb attacks are making wierd results when I initialize them.

Everything is good until I mask the attacks in the last square. My enum square starts from A1 to H8.

So let's say I have loop here:

```
for (all squares) {
  ...
  KingAttacks[square] = maskKingAttacks(square);
}
```

Then this is the maskKingAttacks function:

```
long bb = sqBb(square), attacks = 0L;

// example square is H8, so the bitboard is going to be this:
a b c d e  f g h
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 8

So when I shift it into any direction, exmaple, `bb >> 1`. It will fill up all the square bits. It should only move that one bit but in my case, it fills up everything, If you don't get what I mean is like `bits between from the H8 to G8`.

Note that this only happens when the square is the last square. How do I prevent this? And how will I mask attacks in the last square?
```